# how to passing variable inside button click function to another click function and make into parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna ask about is possible if I have one button click function (modal value) and getting all data for my update requirement and passing into button confirmation (update button) and edit my data?

for code I explain in bellow :

```
/* button edit click */
$("#data-items").on('click', '#edit', function () {
    /* get id from attribute */
    const getId = $(this).attr("data-edit");
    $.ajax({
        url: `my-web/my-url/${getId}`,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            id_item: getId,
        },
        success: function (success) {
            /* showing modal */
            $("#edit-item").modal("show");
            /* get data item and insert into input type */
            const getIdItem = success['get_data']['id_item'];
            const getNameItem = success['get_data']['name_item'];

            $("input[name='item-name']").val(getNameItem);

            // example 1
            $("#my-update-button").on('click', function () {
                 console.log(getIdItem);
            });

            // example 2
            // I wanna passing the getIdItem into my-update-button but I still don't know how to do that
        }
    });
});

// example 2
$("#my-update-button").on('click', function (getIdItem) {
    console.log(getIdItem); <= but the data giving undefined
});
```

**More Explain (I'm afraid my explanation in above is not good enough)**

- Example 1 : I wanna make my update button inside my data-item function click but it's not working and nothing happened.
- Example 2 : I wanna make data in variable `getIdItem` into parameter and passing into update button function and I still don't know how to do that.

*If my explanation still make everyone confused about my problem you can ask me in the comment, I need your help, thank you before*

Comment: Just initialize the variable globally and assign a value to that in first button click and use same variable to you second button click

Comment: thanks for answer sir, is possible if I don't use global variable sir?

Comment: Hi , myupdate button is inside modal ? if yes you can add hidden input with that value inside modal and access them whenever update button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Swati, yes my update button inside the modal, I do with my project before but now I wanna make my value isn't inside my input